# How to update using column in same table (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a question to ask.

There is a Table name 'T1' with columns 'empno(pk)', 'deptno', 'sort_order'

sort_order column, is bit messy. It's works well but looks bad... so I want update rows using Rank() over.

```
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY sort_order ASC) AS new_sorder
```

I have no idea how to update sort_order column with the value of NEW_SORDER.
I tried with 'MERGE INTO' It works really well, but I want to know is there any way NOT using 'MERGE INTO'.

This is what I tried...

```
UPDATE  t1 A 
set A.sort_order = (SELECT B.sort_order FROM
(SELECT     empno,
            deptno,
            RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY deptno
            ORDER BY     sort_order ASC ) AS new_sorder
FROM    t1 B
ORDER BY deptno, sort_order) B
WHERE A.empno = B.empno);
```

I solved the problem,(I don't know how I solved.... wth....)
and this is what I used.(there is one more column name 'dept_order' use for ordering results)

```
UPDATE t1 a SET sort_order = (
Select new_order 
FROM (
select empno,deptno, rank() over (partition by deptno, dept_order
                                 order by sort_order) new_order 
        FROM t1
        ) b
WHERE a.empno = b.empno 
AND a.deptno = b.deptno );
```

Comment: I would use `merge`, it is more readable when used with functions like `rank()`. But your query works too: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cef828debe5761081fffd7c59e149565). Could you explain what is wrong?

Comment: Tk for your comment Ponder. Somehow, It doesn't work yesterday but now it work.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use update with subquery as follows:

```
UPDATE T1 A
   SET
    A.SORT_ORDER = (
        SELECT B.NEW_SORDER
          FROM (
            SELECT EMPNO,
                   RANK() OVER(
                       PARTITION BY DEPTNO
                        ORDER BY SORT_ORDER ASC
                   ) AS NEW_SORDER
              FROM T1 B
        ) B 
         WHERE A.EMPNO = B.EMPNO
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `rank()` in your query.  But you can emulate that with a subquery:

```
update t1
    set sort_order = (select 1 + count(distinct tt1.sort_order)
                      from t1 tt1
                      where tt1.dept_id = t1.dept_id and tt1.sort_order < t1.sort_order
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE IMP_INVOICE_TAX SET TAX_AMT=TAX_AMT/2
WHERE (INVOICE_NO,ITEM_KEY_ID,TAX_AMT) IN(
    SELECT  INVOICE_NO,ITEM_KEY_ID,TAX_AMT
    FROM IMP_INVOICE_TAX
    WHERE INVOICE_NO=1461009999
)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.